# Retrieve ACF unique ID generated by repeater field for use in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advanced custom fields to repeat divs. There is a unique ID injected into the wrapper div for a click function that reveals content (i can't use a class because it triggers all the divs at once).

How do I target this ID in my javascript function dynamically? Here is my code;

```
    <?php if( have_rows('team') ): $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('team') ): the_row(); $i++;

            $image = get_sub_field('image');
            $position = get_sub_field('position');
            $name = get_sub_field('name');
            $bio = get_sub_field('bio');

            ?>

            <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" style="float: left;">
                <div class="card">
                    <button class="teamInfo" id="wrap-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content light-grey-bg">
                            <p class="card-title hind bold dark-grey caps"><span class="center"><?php echo $position; ?></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-action blue-bg center text-center">
                            <p class="hind bold white caps"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <div class="card-reveal" id="show-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <span class="card-title hind bold caps dark-grey"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right !important;">
                                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </button>
                        <p class="hind dark-grey pt1"><?php echo $bio; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And my function;

```
<script>
    (function($) {

        $('#wrap-1').on('click',function(){
            $('#show-1').slideToggle('slow');
        });
        $('#show-1 .close').on('click',function(){
            $('#show-1').slideToggle('slow');
        });

    })( jQuery );
</script>
```

Edit: the id is dynamically injected here;

```
id="wrap-<?php echo $i; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the ID to each element in a data attribute, and use `this` and that ID to toggle appropriately. To summarize the JS, when you click on the button, you get the stored data attribute, which can be used to find the appropriate target for toggling.

To the HTML, I add the data ID to the #show divs, and removed the id completely from the button.  It's not needed.

**HTML changes:**

```
<button class="teamInfo" data-toggle-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

and

```
<div class="card-reveal" id="show-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">`
```

**Javascript**

```
(function($) {

    $('.teamInfo').on('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).data('toggle-id');
        $('#show-' + id).slideToggle();
    });


    $('.card-reveal .close').on('click',function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('.card-reveal').data('toggle-id');
        $('#show-' + id).slideToggle('slow');
    });

})( jQuery );
```

And the entire HTML as you posted it:

```
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-4 columns" style="float: left;">
    <div class="card">
        <button class="teamInfo" data-toggle-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content light-grey-bg">
                <p class="card-title hind bold dark-grey caps"><span class="center"><?php echo $position; ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action blue-bg center text-center">
                <p class="hind bold white caps"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div class="card-reveal" id="show-<?php echo $i; ?>" data-toggle-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <span class="card-title hind bold caps dark-grey"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float: right !important;">
                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times blue" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </button>
            <p class="hind dark-grey pt1"><?php echo $bio; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Very well done. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at using [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). You can still use a class for an event selector, and in the handler, have context to know which was selected.

```
<script>
    (function($) {

        $('.teamInfo').on('click',function(){
            $(this).slideToggle('slow');
        });
        $('.teamInfo').on('click',function(){
            $(this).slideToggle('slow');
        });

    })( jQuery );
</script>
```

^ i'm not clear if you were adding the `.close` class for a visual cue or if you wanted to use that to trach shown state. Might just need the one handler to act as a toggle. Or an if statement in the toggle if other things need to happen on the transition.